# Setting ExpressionTextBox's ExpressionType to a generic type

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I'm having a slight problem using the **ExpressionTextBox** control in a designer for an activity that I have. How does one go about setting its **ExpressionType** property in XAML to a **Type** object that defines the **IEnumerable`1** generic? I can get away with not setting it at all, but ideally I'd like to get validation support at design time for the control with this.

I've tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
<View:ExpressionTextBox 
   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
   Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.SelectedDestinations, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=Out}" 
   ExpressionType="{x:Type TypeName=Generic:IEnumerable[Communication:CommunicationDeliveryDestination]}" 
   OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}" />
```

Any ideas in how to properly set the **ExpressionType** property in XAML? Below is the full XAML of the designer for my activity.

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="UrbanScience.ELS.Orchestration.Activities.Design.SelectDestinationsByLeadDestinationTypeDesigner"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:sapc="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:Generic="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
                      xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>

    <Grid Height="50">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Lead Destination Type:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <ComboBox Name="LeadDestinationTypeItems" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="OnLeadDestinationTypeChanged" />

        <TextBlock Text="Assign selected destinations to:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <View:ExpressionTextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.SelectedDestinations, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=Out}"
                                ExpressionType="{x:Type TypeName=Generic:IEnumerable[Communication:CommunicationDeliveryDestination]}"
                                OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        </View:ExpressionTextBox>
    </Grid>
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ModelItem` to get property type and bind to it, like this:

```xml
ExpressionType={Binding ModelItem.Properties[SelectedDestinations].PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]}
```

Comment: To me it's not clear what _SelectedDestinations_ means here. Can you add a realworld example. e.g. for a `public InArgument<T> ActualValue { get; set; }`, would the actual binding in XAML look like `ExpressionType="{Binding ModelItem.Properties[ActualValue].PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]}"`? Thanks.