# How to bind a checkbox and drop down in a WorkflowActivityDesigner to a parameter in the CodeActivity?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How can I bind a checkbox and drop down  in a WorkflowActivityDesigner to a parameter in the CodeActivity?  I was able to finally connect the designer with the activity using this: [Designer(typeof(ActivityDesigner1))].  But the question remains, how do I consume the values from the designer surface into

Here is my codeactivity file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WorkflowConsoleApplication1
{
    [Designer(typeof(ActivityDesigner1))]
    public sealed class CodeActivity1 : NativeActivity
    {
        // Define an activity input argument of type string
        public InArgument<string> Text { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);
            Console.WriteLine(this.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my designer xaml file:

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="WorkflowConsoleApplication1.ActivityDesigner1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation" Height="68">
    <sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <ImageDrawing>
                    <ImageDrawing.Rect>
                        <Rect Location="0,0" Size="16,16" />
                    </ImageDrawing.Rect>
                    <ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="TES16x16icon.gif" />
                    </ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
                </ImageDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="34,6,0,-18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Name="txtSubject" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-5.46"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393616/setting-expressiontextboxs-expressiontype-to-a-generic-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Partial answer available here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393616/setting-expressiontextboxs-expressiontype-to-a-generic-type)